# Excel SAP GUI Compile error label not defined

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, sap-gui

I have this SAP GUI script that I have recorded as seen below. The macro should be able to export it to an excel sheet. However, I need a way to where it will actually populate the excel sheet. However i keep getting this error: label not found. Can someone please help me out ? I saw this question on this right here: [How to run SAP GUI script from Excel Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187903/how-to-run-sap-gui-script-from-excel-macro)

However, I followed it almost identically and I'm trying to troubleshoot where I'm messing up.

RAW SAP MACRO RECORDER:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "ZPRS"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_PLANT").text = "1707"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").text = "BSLSR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
```

looking at the link and changing it up to what I *thought was correct*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_NoSAP

If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
End If

If (Connection.Children.Count > 1) Then GoTo Err_TooManySAP

Set aw = SAP_session.ActiveWindow()
aw.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize

On Error GoTo Err_Description

session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ZPRS"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_PLANT").Text = "1707"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").Text = "BSLSR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

but then I get error that says :

> Compile error: label not defined

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this ?

Comment: `Err_NoSAP:` is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on first look you are using error handlers like `On Error GoTo Err_NoSAP`. There is nowhere in your posted code line with error handler like `Err_NoSAP:`,  where code should after occured  error jump into.