# SAP Logon from Excel, permissions missing?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm working with VBA and GuiXT separated and now I'm trying to use the SAP GUI VBA integration instead, but i think it's not working because I'm missing a permission.

I tried the code I've found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187903/how-to-run-sap-gui-script-from-excel-macro):

```
Sub test()
    Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
    Dim SAPApp As Object
    Dim SAPCon As Object
    Dim session As Object

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
    Set session = SAPCon.Children.ElementAt(0)

    SAPCon.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
End Sub
```

It runs and SAP informs me that a script tries to connect to SAP, but the line `Set session = SAPCon.Children.ElementAt(0)` gives me error 614: "The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index".

So I googled and found out, that I'm missing the option "Script recording and playback" in SAP, it's greyed out. And i googled further and I found out, that I'm missing the permission to record or playback a script.
Because of that I'd like to know: if I don't have the permission in SAP to record or playback a script, then that's the reason for my not working VBA code, right?

Comment: Yes, if the situation is as you described. In case gui scripting is disabled by the admin then you will get that error message. But your code contains an error in the following line 
 anyway. The line `SAPCon.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize` should be `session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure about that line. Then I have to request more permissions for the task, because I can't use the GUI integration as well as RFC and doing the whole task with GuiXT would be a mess.

Comment: @Storax It's worth an answer.

Comment: [Reading](https://help.sap.com/doc/97d2d0bc2ed248a4a85a0bec608704f8/760.01/en-US/sap_gui_scripting_sec_guide.pdf) on SAPGUI scripting security

Comment: Short [docu](http://winshuttle-help.s3.amazonaws.com/transaction/en/ts-adv-guide/10.x/4119.htm#gsc.tab=0) how to enable it on server and client side

Comment: @Sandra Rossi If the scripting was disabled on the SAP server which is the default the OP needs to talk with basis and ask them to set the profile parameter sapgui/user_scripting to TRUE